# Duplicating enities with relationships to another database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am using PHP with Doctrine 2, and MySQL as our database server.

We have a couple of databases and we need to insert the same new data to all of our databases.

The issue is auto_increment values differ, and we have have to copy an entity and its children, so just copying the data from one server to the other does not work. Updating all the auto_increment keys to be the same is a nasty hack and I would like to avoid this.

Is there some generic tool which could aid in copying over new data while maintaining relationships, and inserting new values if required? The relationship information can be determined by foreign keys in the database or even from the annotations for our doctrine entities.

We could re-run the import script on the other servers, but this takes a few hours to run. Being able to export some sql commands and simply re-run them on another server would be ideal.

Otherwise, it sounds like I have an interesting coding project on my hands.

Comment: quick/dirty would be to insert into a temp table set, and if you're using cascading foreign keys, just update the parent records and let things cascade. otherwise you're stuck slurping data into client-side code and then replication the parent/child insert sequence with the new IDs in place there.

Comment: Ah interesting. Different approach I thought of a few seconds was to create & serialize the  new entities, then basically run the import script on this serialized data instead. Hmmm... =)

Comment: serializing wouldn't help too much, since you'd be serializing the potentially duplicate IDs along with everything else.

Comment: True True. Lucky for me the only entities that pre-exists would be tags. All the other entities being associated would be new. I should refactor my code since 99% of the time is prepping the data for import. I could then import based off of the prepped data and run the import against each database, which would be very quick. I still wish there was a clean & generic solution to this issue though. (Sorry for the re-comment, accidentally deleted. Meant to clean up some spelling errors!)